# How to place the last div within a div at the end of the div containing it using css?

Tags: css, reactjs

i have a parent div that contains two span tags and one child div. i want these span tags to be next to each other with spacing 10px and the child div to be at the right end of the parent div

below is the code,

```
render = () =>  {
    return (
        <div class="container">
            <>
                <span size={12} color={theme.colors.text}>
                    first span
                </span>
                <span>
                    second span
                </span>
            </>
            <div>child div </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

could someone help me with this thanks.

below is the css,

```
span {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    padding-bottom: 16px;
    margin-bottom: 16px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do the following:

1. Set the containers `flex-direction:column` and `align-content:space-between`
2. Wrap the `span`s in a `div`, set a [first child](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/f/first-child/) property to `margin-right:10px`
3. Wrap each span in a `div`

Answer (score 0):

Please check this example. Here I used material design:

```
import React from 'react';
import {makeStyles} from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    root: {
        flexGrow: 1,
        margin: 50
    },
    grid: {
        height: 740,
        width: 500,
    },
    gridChild: {
        height: 240,
        width: 180,
        background: "skyblue",
        border: '1px solid blue'
    },
    paper: {
        height: 240,
        width: 200,
    },
    paperChild: {
        height: 50,
        width: 100,
        background: "lightgreen",
        border: '1px solid green'
    },
    control: {
        padding: theme.spacing(2),
    },
}));

export default function SpacingGrid() {
    const classes = useStyles();

    return (
        <Grid container className={classes.root} spacing={2}>
            <Grid item xs={12} className={classes.grid}>
                <Grid container justify="center" spacing={2}>
                    <Grid key="1" item className={classes.gridChild}>
                        <Grid container item xs={12}>
                            <Paper className={classes.paperChild}>Paper 1</Paper>
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid container item xs={12}>
                            <Paper className={classes.paperChild} >Paper 2</Paper>
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid key="2" item className={classes.gridChild}>
                        <Paper className={classes.paperChild}>Paper 3</Paper>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    );
}
```